# Why there is NullPointerException in the following code?

Tags: java, arrays

The below code shows **NullPointerException**

```
public class Q117d { 
    static int[] a;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        a[-1] = 2;
    }
}
```

The below code shows ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

```
public class Q117c{
    static int[] a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a=new int[5];
        a[0]=2;
        a[2]=3;
        a[-1]=2;
    }
}
```

Why both the codes are showing different exceptions where as in both a[-1] should be null?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should make that more clear.

Comment: clear in what sense?

Comment: Clear in the sense of actually saying that it's a homework question, instead of... not.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Whether it's a homework question or not is not a very relevant piece of information...

Comment: @assylias See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812).

Comment: @RedRoboHood This is an endless discussion but as far as I am concerned, I fail to see what difference it would make to say this is a homework question: I judge questions based on their content, not based on the context in which they are asked. In this specific example the question is (somewhat) clear, it has a full, compilable example that reproduces the problem and it is answerable. So it looks fine to me (it probably has numerous duplicates but that's a different issue).

Comment: @assylias Since it is "an endless discussion" instead of a resolved issue, you shouldn't be asserting your viewpoint as fact or official policy. In this case, the question doesn't list a single attempt on the part of the asker to solve the problem. If he is simply trying to get Stack Overflow to solve his homework problem without putting any effort in himself, that goes against the guidelines for asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Because in the first you haven't initialized a. You start with declaring a variable, which will allocate some memory. But only when you tell by `a = new int[10]` will the an exact amount of memory be allocated for, in this case, 10 integers... Without telling the size of this array, they is an allocation to nowhere (null)

In the second you have initialized, so there is a memory allocation for the array. But there is no a[-1] declared because arrays start counting at index 0

Answer (score 2):

From your first code (**NullPointerException**).You didn't initialize `a`, so when you trying to add something to a NullPointerException exceptions will occur.

Second code (**ArrayIndexOutOfBound**).You initializing a with `size 5`.Now array index strat with `0`, but you try to put `a[-1]`, so ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception will occur.